# Unable to translate LINQ Query

Tags: sql, linq

I am having an issue with the following LINQ query:

```
var baselineDate = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-365);
        var salesPerformance = _context.SalesOrder.Where(p => p.OrderDate >= baselineDate).Where(p => p.CustomerId == customerId)
                               .GroupBy(p => p.OrderDate.Month)
                               .Select(g => new CustomerSalesPerformance
                               {
                                   Month = g.Key,
                                   Sales = g.Sum(i => i.SalesOrderItems.Sum(i => i.Qty * i.UnitPrice))
                               });

        return await salesPerformance.ToListAsync();
```

I am aiming to produce a report with sales per customer for the last year:

Jan: £13,500
Feb: £0.00
Mar: £56,000
etc

I am unable to see anything in this query which would not translate (such as a DateTime function).

The error message:

> {"The LINQ expression 'GroupByShaperExpression:\r\nKeySelector: DATEPART(month, s.OrderDate), \r\nElementSelector:EntityShaperExpression: \r\n    EntityType: SalesOrder\r\n    ValueBufferExpression: \r\n        ProjectionBindingExpression: EmptyProjectionMember\r\n    IsNullable: False\r\n\r\n    .Sum(i => i.SalesOrderItems\r\n        .Sum(i => (Nullable)i.Qty * i.UnitPrice))' could not be translated. Either rewrite the query in a form that can be translated, or switch to client evaluation explicitly by inserting a call to 'AsEnumerable', 'AsAsyncEnumerable', 'ToList', or 'ToListAsync'. See https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2101038 for more information."}

My models:

**SalesOrder**
SalesOrderId (PK, int)
CustomerId (FK, int)
OrderDate (DateTime)

**SalesOrderItem**
SalesOrderItemId (PK, int)
Qty (int)
UnitPrice (decimal)
SalesOrderId (FK, int)

My DTO Model:

**CustomerSalesPerformance**
Month (int)
Sales (decimal?)

Comment: I assume you are using EF Core? Best to specify what LINQ - LINQ to Objects / SQL / EF 6.x / EF Core 2.0 / 2.1 / 3.x / 5.x.

Comment: EF Core 3.x has a problem with translating complicated group by. It also has a problem with some simple group by :) that they are working on fixing. 5.0 fixes some, still some issues to go. You could either add `.AsEnumerable()` for client side processing of the groupby, or change the double `.Sum()` which I think is breaking your translation, but need to know which EF Core to be sure.

Comment: Hi I am using EF Core 5.0.1. I have been using Dapper for more complex query commands. It isn't the double sum as I removed that and had the same issue. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After GroupBy, you cannot use navigation properties. So just rewrite query to do that before.

```cs
var salesPerformance = 
    from so in _context.SalesOrder
    where so.OrderDate >= baselineDate && so.CustomerId == customerId)
    from sio in so.SalesOrderItems
    group sio by so.OrderDate.Month into g
    select new CustomerSalesPerformance
    {
        Month = g.Key,
        Sales = g.Sum(i => ii.Qty * i.UnitPrice)
    });
```

Comment: Perfect. Thank you.